# Remove a substring from a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large (45K rows) dataset and I need to remove specific values from specific columns in a handful of cases. The dataset is large enough I'd like to avoid using `apply` if at all possible.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [30, 40, 50], "T": ["C", "D", "E"], "S": ["n", "o/p", "p"]})

drops = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [40, 50],"Column": ["S", "S"],"Rule": ["Remove", "Remove"],"Override": ["p", "p"]})
```

My current solution is to use:

```
(
df.merge(
    drops.pivot(index="ID", columns="Column", values="Override").reset_index()[["ID", "S"]],
    how="left",
    on=["ID", "S"],
    indicator="_dropS",
).assign(
    S=lambda d_: d_.S.mask(d_._dropS == "both", np.nan)))
```

But this only successfully removes one of the entries. My general Python knowledge is telling me to split the column `S` by the delimiter "/", remove the matching entry, and join the list back together again (there may be more than two entries in the `S` column), but I can't seem to make that work within the DataFrame without using `apply`.

Edited to add goal state: Column `S` should have the entries: 'n', 'o', ''. The final could be NaN as well.

Is there a reasonable way to do this without a separate function call?

Comment: not sure if I understand right. in your real data you have like a drops_df which tells you the id's, then the column to look for (here `S`) and which letter/word should be removed from that column. If this cell only contains the target letter, make it Nan? and instead only remove that letter, leaving the rest untouched. is that right ? maybe you could add a desired output for your sample data, I think that'll help

Comment: I added an edit to try to explain this a bit better. If you consider the entries of `S` to be lists delimited by "/", I'm trying to remove a list item and rejoin the list if necessary. That part seems simple, it's the doing it in pandas that's the bugaboo.

Comment: Your problem is not properly explained. Please give us input sample, drop criteria and expected outcome. Your code is not so helpful especially if it does not do what you want it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC here is one solution that gives the expected output, no idea about the perfomance. Would be interested in your feedback on that.

```
#from your sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [30, 40, 50], "T": ["C", "D", "E"], "S": ["n", "o/p", "p"]})
drops = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [40, 50],"Column": ["S", "S"],"Rule": ["Remove", "Remove"],"Override": ["p", "p"]})

pivoted_rules = drops.pivot(index="ID", columns="Column", values="Override").rename(columns={'S': 'compare_S'})

res = pd.concat([df.set_index('ID'),pivoted_rules],axis=1).fillna('fill_value')
res['S'] = [''.join([x for x in a if x!=b]) for a, b in zip(res['S'].str.split('/'), res['compare_S'])]
res = res.drop('compare_S', axis=1).reset_index()

print(res)

    ID  T   S
0   30  C   n
1   40  D   o
2   50  E
```

Didn't use `apply` :)

Comment: Yes, this gets me where I need to be and it doesn't slow down the overall process by any considerable margin. I was worried that zipping two columns together would be costly, but it doesn't appear to be. Probably because that's the sort of thing pandas was built for.

Answer (score 0):

remove specific values from specific columns,you can use .str.replace

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [30, 40, 50], "T": ["C", "D", "E"], "S": ["n", "o/p", "p"]})
df.loc[:,'S'] = df['S'].str.replace(r'[/p]','')
```

the result :

```
   ID  T  S
0  30  C  n
1  40  D  o
2  50  E
```